# How to get the largest value from list of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo document:

```js
"apps" : {
    "a" : {
        "last_login" : ISODate("2013-08-07T10:18:39.371Z")
    },
    "b" : {
        "last_login" : ISODate("2013-08-21T09:53:10.769Z")
    },
    "c" : {
        "last_login" : ISODate("2013-08-30T09:53:10.769Z")
    },
}
```

I want to get the highest last_login value? How do I do it?

Comment: is this one document? or is `apps` the collection? can you add some real data to the question?

Comment: What do you mean by highest? The most recent?

Comment: You should probably change your schema and use arrays as described by @Neil in his answer. Your current schema will complicate things for you.

Comment: xlembouras: This is just one document. Will try to add real data.
alistair: yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "answer": { "$cond": [
            { "$gt": [ "$a.last_login", "$b.last_login" ] },
            { "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$a.last_login", "$c.last_login" ] },
                { 
                    "key": { "$literal": "a" }, 
                    "last_login": "$a.last_login"
                },
                {
                    "key": { "$literal": "c" },
                    "last_login": "$c.last_login"
                }
            ]},
            { "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$b.last_login", "$c.last_login" ] },
                {
                    "key": { "$literal": "b" },
                    "last_login": "$b.last_login"
                },
                {
                    "key": { "$literal": "c" },
                    "last_login": "$c.last_login"
                },
            ]}
        ]}
    }}
])
```

It works, but it's actually quite mental. So the lesson to learn here it *"do not use sub-documents in this way"*, and use **arrays** instead:

```js
{
    "apps": [
      { "type": "a", "last_login": ISODate("2013-08-07T10:18:39.371Z") },
      { "type": "b", "last_login": ISODate("2013-08-21T09:53:10.769Z") },
      { "type": "c", "last_login": ISODate("2013-08-30T09:53:10.769Z") }
    ]
}
```

That makes things much more simple:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    { "$unwind": "$apps" },
    { "$sort": { "apps.last_login": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "answer": { "$first": "$apps" }
    }}
])
```

Much easier isn't it.

**NOTE:** The [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal) operator was introduced in MongoDB 2.6. You might possibly find some references on the net to **`$const`** as an alternate operator, but this is not actually officially supported as that operator actually exists for another purpose.

You can do exactly the same thing in earlier server versions of MongoDB using the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator instead:

```js
"key": { "$cond": [ 1, "a", 0 ] }
```

This works as the result arguments to [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) are actually delivered as "literal" values, or "whatever you type in there", so no variable substitutions.

Comment: your NOTE is wrong. $const and $literal are aliases. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pipeline/expression.cpp#L797-798